# If $\binom{n+2}{5}=12\binom{n}3$ what is n.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> If $\binom{n+2}{5}=12\binom{n}3$ what is n.

I have tried taking the long way of breaking down what (n+2C5) and 12(nC3) are. However, it has led me to a wrong answer.

The tip is:

> Use the property:  $\binom nk=\frac{n}k\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$

Comment: You only need to use the tip twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${n+2\choose 5} = 12{n\choose 3}$$

So $${(n+2)!\over 5!\cdot (n-3)!}=12{n!\over 3!(n-3)!}$$

So $${(n+2)(n+1)n!\over 5\cdot 4\cdot 3! (n-3)!}=12{n!\over 3!(n-3)!}$$

So $${(n+2)(n+1)\over 20} =12$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: You also have it true when $\binom{n}{3}=0,$ that is, when $n=0,1,2.$

Comment: What about $-1$? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Depends on how you define it, but some people define $\binom{y}{k}$ in terms of the coefficient of $x^k$ in the power series $(1+x)^y,$ in which case $\binom{-1}{k}=(-1)^k,$ for $k\geq 0.$ But other times, we leave $\binom{-1}{k}=0,$ especially for combinatorial purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was on the correct path but messed up. It has been over 6 years since I did any intensive mathematics. I completely forgot about how to derive n from the quadratic formula ^^ just brushed my knowledge on the -b formula.

Answer (score 1):

$${n+2\choose 5} = 12{n\choose 3}\implies (n+2)(n+1)=240 $$

The positive answer which is acceptable is $n=14$

Comment: Might be useful to mention the "tip" OP stated can be used twice to derive this implication (as JG mentions in a comment above).

Comment: Thank you for your solution.